# HTTP Status 404-Not found, facing this error while trying to load the war file on tomcat webserver

Tags: http, tomcat, webserver, war, war-filedeployment

I've deployed a war file to the apache tomcat webserver successfully using ansible playbook. But when I try to load the war file using myip-address:8080/war file name I'm getting the following error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eDk6A.png)

I'm new to tomcat. Can anyone kindly help me with this error?

Answer (score 0):

The path of the application can be tricky, in order of difficulty from easier to harder:

1. Check the folder name in the tomcat webapp folder, try that relative path in the URL
2. Check the context.xml file in the Tomcat Installation, maybe there is something custom
3. Install the "manager" Tomcat app that allows you to see deployed apps (after some configuration in XMLs)

The point of your error is that the local path /latest contains nothing.